# "Error importing middleware" while upgrading to Django 1.5 from Django 1.4?

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django

I have a shared hosting account with Python 2.7.2 installed. I have done a local installation of Django 1.4 (`python setup.py install --user`) and everything was working fine.

I decided to upgrade to Django 1.5 on the server since I had tested the application locally with Django 1.5 and everything was working fine.

However, after running the upgrade (`python setup.py install --user`, same as last time), the server started throwing HTTP 500 errors. A quick check of the Apache error log revealed:

```
[Fri Jul 12 00:14:01 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImproperlyConfigured:
  Error importing middleware django.contrib.auth.middleware: "cannot import
  name _doctest"
```

Any idea what could cause this? The error seems to indicate that something is wrong with the `auth` middleware component - it's attempting to load a module (`_doctest`) that does not exist (which I can confirm with `import _doctest`).

In the meantime, I immediately reverted back to Django 1.4 and everything is working again.